# Send a Message to another textbox Application

Tags: c#, sendmessage, spy++

i try to send Messages from one Application to another Application..

I think the Code works perfectly and is not the problem, but the text is sending to the wrong textbox? I looked with Spy++, and i have two textboxes in Application 2, but for both textboxes i return the same Class from Spy++ ---> "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.141b42a_r13_ad1"...

My Main Question is now, why have both textboxes the same "class" and how can i fix this? thx

```
    private const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindows);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern Int32 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Form1");
        if (!hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            IntPtr edithWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.141b42a_r13_ad1", null);
            if (!edithWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
            SendMessage(edithWnd, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, new StringBuilder("Hello World!"));
        }
    }
```

//Working Stuff...

```
            IntPtr edithWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.141b42a_r12_ad1", null);
            IntPtr nextHnd = edithWnd;
            IntPtr editWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, nextHnd, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.141b42a_r12_ad1", null);
            IntPtr nextHnd1 = editWnd;
            IntPtr editWnd1 = FindWindowEx(hWnd, nextHnd1, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.141b42a_r12_ad1", null);
            IntPtr nextHnd2 = editWnd1;
            IntPtr editWnd2 = FindWindowEx(hWnd, nextHnd2, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.141b42a_r12_ad1", null);
```

Comment: You could iterate over all running processes and then get the [MainWindowHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle(v=vs.110).aspx) for the other instance by comparing process id's (so that you exclude the current process). Your first FindWindow call can then become `FindWindowxEx(process.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Form1", null);`

Comment: @rene Thanks, it works now (edit: working stuff), and hope this is the right way :)

Comment: @rene Still one Problem left :/ Cant get a new line? new StringBuilder("Hello World!" + Environment.NewLine)); or new StringBuilder("Hello World! \r\n")); not work in the other application :(

Comment: If that textbox isn't configured to be [`Multiline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff(v=vs.110).aspx) I don't think you'll see that new line.

Comment: @rene that was too my first thought, but i have already Multiline activated ;S